# What is the point of the HR questions during programmer interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, human-resources, software-development, developer

Seriously, there is a set of HR questions which are IMO plain stupid and pretty ridiculous. I had interview today for a position which was 1000% match on my CV in my opinion one of two options happened:
1) I failed the HR part
OR
2) They were just looking for reason to fail me because they had another candidate.

In any case I think I answered flawlessly the technical part because I had a previous project that was extremely similar solving most of the problem they were trying to solve in their project. I have 100% domain match.

But the HR got annoyed because in my CV - which is generated CV where you place some skills and rate them as well as mark how many years you have used them and when was the last time using them. So she got annoyed because I have marked all the skills with 5 stars, now I have a lot of skills which I dont feel so comfortable but then I just dont list them and what is the point of listing them I have 20 years experience and I list what I am feel best in.

And them a set of the regular idiotic questions like. What is your team thinking about you. What animal would you like to be. Tell us a strong side and a weak side. Maaaaannn... and then suddenly I got immediate rejection. And I am 100% sure that my technical part was not the problem.

Why the HRs are allowed to screw up the interviews ? Whats the point of all that ? What is the problem that I have placed stupid stars, it could have been hearts or violins....

Comment: While I appreciate your frustration, is there some actual problem we can help with? As this seems entirely like just a rant reaction to a rejection, which I agree sucks, but, well, we cannot really help with.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul yes I want to understand what is the point of these questions in a programming interview. How is this a good reason to turn down a good candidate beyond this questions. How can you get annoyed by a number of stars on a skill. Which is entirely personal perseption in an interview where there is supposed to be a technical person evaluating skills.

Comment: Soft skills are as important, especially the more senior you get. And anyone who ranks themselves as 5 star in something is either author of this technology or bending the truth. Anyway, it was your cv, you wrote it, why create it into such a form? All this aside, I have to VTC as this isn't really a question I think we can answer here.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul It was not my CV, it was a generated CV I was asked to put some skills and rate them and place when how long I have used it and when I have used it last.

Comment: Your question is just a rant. There is no point in asking "why". You should be asking us "how" do I succeed the next time around? or "how" do I make sure an HR person doesn't screen me out without consulting with the hiring manager first? Those answers are out there, you're just not seeking them out.

Answer (score 23):

**I suspect you failed on personality**

If the irritation you show in this post even slightly came off during your interview, you got tagged as having a problem personality. If you get this annoyed at a couple random questions, it does not bode well for future interactions.

Comment: Yup. That. As I read this post, its formulations and obvious lack of self-reflection, I immediately thought, "I would veto this on my team, no matter the technical skill".

Comment: I agree. An interview is not just an assessment of skills. It's an advertisement of everything you are as a potential employee.

Answer (score 7):

Because there's more to being a good employee than programming skills.  They want to know how you interact with other people, how you react when presented with off-the-wall questions, and so on.

If they give you the job, you will most likely be in a project or department team.  How you work with them is just as important as what your skills are.